# Why does 'echo "alias g=/home/user/examplescript" >> ~/.bash_aliases' produce this error: "no authorisation"?

Tags: bash, raspbian, alias, echo

When I try this code in Raspbian Buster terminal:

```
echo "alias g=/home/user/examplescript" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

I get the error `Authorisation Error`. Following code works without problem:

```
echo "alias g=/home/user/examplescript" >> ~/.bashrc
```

But I want to store my aliases in ~/.bash_aliases. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the output of the command `ls -ld ~/.bash_aliases ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Input: `ls -ld ~/.bash_aliases ~/.bashrc`
Output: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   58 Mai 11 17:56 /home/user123/.bash_aliases -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 3523 Mai 11 18:35 /home/user123/.bashrc`. Do I have to change root to user? how?

Comment: Do you really see the message “Authorisation Error”? If this is your translation, please don't do that. Never translate error messages. The exact choice of words, even the punctuation is relevant. Run `export LC_MESSAGES=C` and then run the command again to get messages in English.

Answer (score 1):

For one reason or another, your `~/.bash_aliases` file is [owned by root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585994/why-does-echo-alias-g-home-user-examplescript-bash-aliases-produce-th/585995#comment1091456_585994) and is not writable by you.

Change the owner of the file to your own user:

```
sudo chown user:group ~/.bash_aliases
```

... where `user:group` should reflect your username and your primary group.  You username is given by the `id -un` command, and the primary group by `id -gn`, for reference.

Comment: perfect, thanks! This works as I intended!

Comment: @Mips You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).